# How to expand a build flag into an environment dict?

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules-js

I am trying to make my build configurable with a custom flag.

It should be possible to specify the flag value when I build, e.g.

```bash
bazel build //test:bundle --//:foo_flag=bar
```

Here is my build target definition (using [rules_js](https://github.com/aspect-build/rules_js)):

```
load("@npm//:defs.bzl", "npm_link_all_packages")
load("@npm//test:webpack-cli/package_json.bzl", "bin")

npm_link_all_packages(
  name = "node_modules",
)

bin.webpack_cli(
  name = "bundle",
  outs = [
    "out/index.html",
    "out/main.js",
  ],
  args = [
    "--config",
    "webpack.config.js",
    "-o",
    "out",
  ],
  srcs = [
    "webpack.config.js",
    ":node_modules",
  ] + glob([
    "src/**/*.js",
  ]),
  chdir = package_name(),
  env = {
    # ?
  },
  visibility = [
    "//visibility:public",
  ],
)
```

What is unclear from the various Bazel examples is how to actually pass the flag to the rule.

I am looking for something like this:

```
# Invalid

  env = {
    "FOO": "$(value //:foo_flag)",
  },
```

How do I pass a flag in Bazel?

Answer (score 0):

To use the command-line flag, you want to use a [`config_setting()`](https://bazel.build/reference/be/general#config_setting) and then `select()` based on that.

```py
config_setting(
  name = "foo_flag_set",
  flag_values = { "//:foo_flag": "bar" },
)

...

bin.webpack_cli(
  name = "bundle",
  ...
  env = select({
    ":foo_flag_set": {...},
    "//conditions:default": None,
  },
  ...
)
```

This might be the way to go, if you have a distinct set of values for your flag. Otherwise you might want to think about a `--action_env` flag.

Comment: I am currently using `--action_env` but that affects all genrules so is not ideal. Is there not a way to put the value of the flag into the `env`? It's surprising how difficult this is!

Answer (score 0):

Set them with the [`--define`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--define) flag. Values set like that will be expanded in any context that performs ["Make" variable expansion](https://bazel.build/reference/be/make-variables). That looks like this:

```py
bin.webpack_cli(
  name = "bundle",
  ...
  env = {
    "FOO": "$(FOO)",
  },
)
```

and then build with `--define=FOO=bar`.

I can't find the docs for `bin.webpack_cli` to confirm it does "Make" variable expansion in `env`, but most `env` attributes do so I'm assuming it does. For example rules_docker's [`container_layer.env`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/docs/container.md#user-content-container_layer-env) mentions this in its documentation.

Comment: Does `--define` affect all rules though?